# .Net 4.5 Required Field not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

With required fields, I am able to submit a form without putting data in.

The same global.asax file worked on another site for unobtrusive validation.

Here is a HTML:

```
    <p>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFirstName" AssociatedControlID="txtFirstName">

            First name:

            <span class="soft">

                (required)

            </span>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="reqFirstName" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" CssClass="red label" Text="Required" />

        </asp:Label>

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstName" MaxLength="50" />
    </p>
```

Here is the global.aspx

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

   Dim Item As New ScriptResourceDefinition

    With Item

        .Path = "/assets/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"

        .DebugPath = "/assets/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"

        .CdnPath = "//ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"


        .CdnDebugPath = "//ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"

    End With

    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", Item)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding validation group to both validator and button.

Comment: Off the top of my head, this looks correct. Have you confirmed there are no other issues on your page such as unrelated JavaScript errors?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using classic WebForms validation then in click handler for the button you need to check if page is valid:

```
if (Page.IsValid())
{
     // you logic
}
```

For client validation you will need to do validation in javascript. Attach OnClientClick handler for the asp button and use jquery validator to check if form is valid

Answer (score 0):

It appears you might be confusing HTML5 form attributes with the asp.net server validators?

You can submit your form with no data entered in the textbox because the form attribute `required="required"` is missing.

Change:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstName" MaxLength="50" />
```

To:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstName" MaxLength="50" required="required" />
```

And this will prevent form submissions on browsers that support the HTML5 form attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to admit it was a noob mistake on my part and spent a ton of time investigating something as easy. The path for the non-CDN ScriptResourceDefinition was off by a letter. "Assets" was no plural. Thanks again for all your help. Good to know about Page.IsValid.